# Как изменить вид стрелочки назад при использовании Navigation Component?

Tags: android, navigation

Внедряю в проект navigation component. Без него меняла вид стрелочки в теме и это отлично работало:

```
<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_material_chevron_left</item>
```

Теперь же это не работает.
В моем коде activity:

```
setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
 NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
```

Буду очень благодарна за помощь

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте задавать иконку кодом вот так

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_skull)
```

попробуйте это написать как ДО так и ПОСЛЕ вашего

```
setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
 NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
```

есть вероятность того, что эта иконка будет спадать, когда вы будете двигаться между фрагментами.
если это произойдет, то сделайте следующим образом:

```
 navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
           toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_skull)
        }
```